# Eclipse Juno won't run all Junit tests in the package

Tags: eclipse, junit

This issue is in Eclipse Juno. I am working on a project that has a very large bunch of Junit tests (800 +) that exist in various packages beneath a root package. Recently when I right-click on the root package and choose "Run As . . .  Junit Test" Eclipse will only run 100 of the tests.

My Run Configuration has the radio button checked that says "Run all tests in the selected project, package, or source folder:" and points to the correct package.

I've tried deleting my Run Configurations and re-creating them, various project cleans, restarts and etc. and Eclipse always runs exactly 100 tests.

Anyone have any ideas?

Comment: I was able to get around this only by deleting the project, checking the "Delete contents on disk" check box, then deleting all of my Run Configurations, and the finally re-checking out the entire project from SVN. Frustrating. Perhaps it's time to move to JDeveloper?

Comment: I use eclipse Juno and often run test suites with over 10,000 tests and have never had this problem.  Are you sure you were running the correct test suite?

Comment: Yes I was. Another developer here had a similar issue and we solved it by deleting the project as I mentioned earlier. It's weird I know . . .